# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null in recaptcha_ajax.js

Tags: javascript

Im using google recapthca in my site .My site link is http://yundantik.com/tr/ileti%C5%9Fim.html

When I click map image in right in website opening up iframe and close .After getting  'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null'  this error.

You can check in site this error in console.

How can I fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: There are other errors before that: `Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com"` and `NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist. exec (mootools-core.js, line 111)`.

Comment: So What can I do for this error?

Comment: Fix the errors that occur before that one. Reduce the code to the minimum that still displays the behaviour. At that point you'll solve it yourself, or you'll have something that others here can work on. Simply posting a link to a page is expecting others to do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the DOM, you'll probably see a bunch of iframes that are being added when you submit the form. I found that adding

$("iframe").remove();

after the form submit code made my captchas show every time.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the `id` of the div where you want to create the reCaptcha. Check if the `id` is correct. And before create the reCpatcha, check if that `id` really exists:

```
if($("#captcha").length) {
  Recaptcha.create("here_is_your_key", "captcha", {
    theme: "clean"
  });
}
```